# Passing boolean value to v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

How can I access/convert `element.varName` string in v-for loop to be passed as variable name to get the current value of this boolean.

In the following case:

```
<div v-for="(element, index) in elements" :key="index" :class="{included : element.varName, 'cur-el':selected==element.shortName}">
    <div v-html="element.icon"></div>
    {{element.name}}
</div>
```

---

```
el1: false,
el2: false,
selected: undefined,
elements: [
    {
        name: 'element 1',
        icon: `<svg>
                <path></path>
                <rect></rect>
            </svg>`,
        shortName: 'el1',
        varName: this.el1
    },
    /...
]
```

How can my `included` class be a boolean value instead of the actual string, initially I tried with the `shortName` used accessing it as follow:

`element.shortName`
which didn't work, also tried:
`[element.shortName]`
as well as:
`this[element.shortName]`
None of which seems to work, so I tried including the actual reference to that variable by adding it in the object `varName: this.el1`, which also didn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're referencing a data property in other one you should define the second property as computed property :

```
data(){
  return {
   el1: false,
   el2: false,
   selected: undefined,
 }
},
computed:{
  elements(){
   return [
    {
        name: 'element 1',
        icon: `<svg>
                <path></path>
                <rect></rect>
            </svg>`,
        shortName: 'el1',
        varName: this.el1
    }
   ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*The reason why `varName: this.el1` is not updated inside `data` option, is because it's not reactive.*

You can read about that in Vue official documentation [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html?redirect=true).

Back to your question **:**

Try to assign the whole `elements` array in `mounted()` life cycle hook. So, that you can access `this.el1`.

**Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data: {
    el1: false,
    el2: true,
    elements: []
  },
  mounted() {
    this.elements = [
      {
        name: 'element 1',
        shortName: 'el1',
        varName: this.el1
      }, {
        name: 'element 2',
        shortName: 'el2',
        varName: this.el2
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

```css
.included {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(element, index) in elements" :key="index" :class="{included : element.varName}">
    {{element.name}}
</div>
</div>
```